# mod_rewrite to remove .html from address bar without changing links in the html file

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First question. So I have a simple website "website.com" on Apache:

```
website.com
    index.html
    site1.html
    site2.html
```

Within each html I have links to other, in this form:

```
<a href="index.html">main</a>
<a href="site1.html">site1</a>
<a href="site2.html">site2</a>
```

I want the browser to display "website.com/site1" instead of "website.com/site1.html".

I've been playing with it for a few days and I always end up with one of these results:

1. Infinite loop of redirects.
2. Internal server error.
3. Both versions work (eg. "website.com/site1.html" and "website.com/site1") but the .html stays in the address bar.

I don't know what's going on. I can't even break it properly. For example I expected that this .htaccess will throw an error on accessing "website.com/site1", because there is no rule redirecting site1 to site1.html:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=302,QSA]
```

But no - it works, just doesn't delete .html in the address bar.

How Apache knows to redirect "website.com/site1" to "website.com/site1.html" without the proper RewriteRule for it? Is my understanding wrong, that I have to redirect from website.com/site1 to website.com/site1.html to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line at your rules :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=302,QSA]
```

It means to change any `file.html` to `file` only and what you need is to accpet `file` only the redirect it internally to `file.html` like this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L,QSA]
```

But , in this case , the `file.html` will be as is so, if you want to remove `.html` at all try the folowing rules :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*)\.html[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^  /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L]
```

The first two lines after  `RewriteEngine on` will remove `.html` .

The rest of lines will check whthere the request withut extention is `.html` file or not , if it is accpeted `.html` it will be redirected but internally .

Now , both , `site1.html` or `site1` will be `site1` in browser.

By this , you will make sure that file accepet `.html` extention before redirecting and that will seperate this stage of being mixed with error files.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks, accepted. May I ask why there is "\s" in the first RewriteCond? I wouldn't expect whitespace characters in the url.

Comment: Can you tell me what version of apache you are running? I'm running apache 2.4.18 and this code does not work as desired. This code errors and looks for a "/file" name instead of "file" and changes example.com/project.html to example.com//project. mybe you designed this for a newer apache version? Thanks.