# apache .conf file problem: Trying to remove .html from address bar

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running a few personal websites off a ubuntu 16.04 VPS server and I'm trying to modify each site so that no ".html" will appear as the suffix to the website and that www. will not appear as a prefix. I would like the website to work if someone types in these modifiers to the address as well.
So far the www. functionality works well, but I can't seem to make the .html suffix work how I would like.

What I have tried:

- modify each .conf file in apache2/sites-available/ with additional mod_rewrite commands
- restart apache after saving each .conf modification
- read into the apache site for mod_rewrite
- I have referenced this: [mod_rewrite to remove .html from address bar without changing links in the html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079746/mod-rewrite-to-remove-html-from-address-bar-without-changing-links-in-the-html)
- I have not tried enabling .htaccess because .htacess is disabled by default in ubuntu 16.04. It is also not suggested to use by apache so I am heeding their words.

Here's my example code:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

    <Directory /var/www/example.com>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*)\.html[\s?/] [NC]
    RewriteRule ^  /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

    <Directory /var/www/example.com>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-access.log combined
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Even with that .conf file above, all that happens is the website continues to show .html and when .html is removed it gives me a 404. Is it possible that I'm running too many rewrite commands? Do I need to combine them to work? Do I need to put them in another `<directory>` for it to work? Are these supposed to go in the main apache2.conf file instead of each website .conf file? I'm not exactly sure.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Try putting redirect condition for removing .html part in virtualhost for :443(https) as in port 80 first you are redirecting everything to https, so the rest of rule should be read from virtualhost entry of https

Comment: Should I duplicate that part in :443, or move it from :80? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: move it .......

Comment: Thanks for your help. That successfully removes all .html from the pages. However, none of my individual pages are now loading. For instance, example.com/projects is a tab on my navigation bar. If I click it I get a example.com/projects and a 404. Regardless if I change projects to href="projects.html" or href="projects" in the main index.html file, nothing loads and I get a 404. There is no .html shown in the address bar though.

Comment: For clarification, I am getting a 404 not found  with "The requested URL /projects was not found on this server." I think there may be something wrong with the way the directory is input into the .conf file. It should be trying to load "projects" not "/projects"

Comment: Still having a problem with loading /projects. I think it may be a better idea to post this in serverfault or webmasters. Mods let me know if this is a good idea. Thanks!